# "-L -lmylib" is not working as expected in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

Here is the file tree:

```
├── lib
│   ├── mylib.cpp
│   ├── mylib.h
│   └── mylib.o
├── libmylib.a
├── main.cpp
├── main.o
├── Makefile
├── mylib
├── mylib.a
└── myprogram
```

This cmd not work

```
g++ -L/home/xxx/make_test -lmylib  main.o -o myprogram2
/usr/local/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But this will work:

```
g++ main.o libmylib.a -o myprogram
```

I don't know why the error happens? `-L/home/xxx/make_test -lmylib` has covered all the info to find libmylib.a.

There is all the code:

```
# main.cpp
#include "lib/mylib.h"
int main(){
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

```
# mylib.cpp
#include "mylib.h"

int f(){
    return 1;
}

int b(){
    return 2;
}
```

```
#mylib.h
#ifndef MAKE_TEST_MYLIB_H
#define MAKE_TEST_MYLIB_H

extern "C" int f();
extern "C" int b();
#endif //MAKE_TEST_MYLIB_H
```

Comment: When linking with libraries, the order in which you link with the object files and libraries matter. Always add the libraries *last* on the command line. The reason is, when you put it first, there's no one that depends on or uses any of the function from the libraries yet, so it's simply disregarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When static libraries are used, static libraries must be listed ***after*** any modules whose dependencies must be satisfied by that static library.

```
g++ main.o libmylib.a -o myprogram
```

Note that `libmylib.a` is listed ***after*** `main.o`. The `-l` option must follow the same rule:

```
g++ -L/home/xxx/make_test main.o -lmylib -o myprogram2
```

`-l` is just a shortcut for either `libmylib.a` or `libmylib.so`, whichever one actually exists.